# call static function zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend framework 2.
I'm trying to call a static function that I imported from a external library.
The library was imported correctly.

**Now when I'm trying to call the static function within one of the classes he adds my controller path to the function call.
Why does he do that?**

This is the error I get:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Application\Controller\PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found in
>   /www/zendphp7/htdocs/Ivan/Takalot/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/AuthController.php:177

and this is the function from where the call to the static function is made:

```
public function getexcelToDB2()
{ 

$data= array();        
$file =  __DIR__."/MALMASH_CTM_JOBS_LIST.xml";       
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);        
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);       
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed the `phpoffice/phpexcel` via composer, it should be with a leading "\":

```
$objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);
```

That is how we use the PHPExcel classes in our controllers etc. without a an usage/import of further namespaces.

Otherwise PHP looks in the current namespace (`Application\Controller`). You may have a look in the vendor directories of `phpoffice/phpexcel`. Their config should hint you to their "correct" namespaces.

Comment: It worked ! 
but I didn't understand really why.
I'm not using a composer btw - Were developing in a internal environment with no access to internet. (banking system)
what does '\' in front of a class name do in PHP?

Comment: It's nothing to do with Composer or ZF. You are declaring the namespace `Application\Controller` at the top of your file, so all classes in that file are assumed to be in that namespace unless imported from elsewhere or the global namespace is used. The `\` prefix indicates the global namespace, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php.

Comment: @TimFountain Should be the better answer!